# Entity Framework 6- dbset Find with composite primar key does not work

Tags: find, entity-framework-6, composite

I have this table with two columns that comprise the primary key. When I try to find the record can not be found.
Table:

```
 public partial class CITVENDBILL
    {
        public string VNDR_NO { get; set; }
        public string VINV_NO { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string OUR_INV { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public decimal REL_NO { get; set; }
        public string VSHP_NO { get; set; }
    }
```

Find:

```
CITVENDBILL cITVENDBILL = db.CITVENDBILLS.Find(id,rel);
```

I have checked and my syntax and method is correct. Can anyone help?
Des anyone know how you can debug what is EF6 looking for?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Do anyone know how you can debug what is EF6 looking for*

Use SQL Profiler and check the SQL Statement which has been executed by Entity Framework. Once you have it, you can execute it yourself in your SQL Server to understand why nothing is found.